# How can I fade an object which uses the gradient or mesh tool?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, gradient, stroke

I am trying to achieve this look in illustrator.

[image]

I can only do this much using gradient tool in illustrator.

[image]

Can someone tell me how can I make it look fade out like the first picture?

Comment: Does it need to be with a single shape? Have you tried stacking multiple objects? You need to think a bit outside the box with this one.

Comment: I am trying with multiple objects using gradients. Will save time if there is a shortcut to it.

Comment: If you're doing it with multiple objects then you can find the answer yourself. How much have you learned about gradients?

Comment: Definitely not an expert. If I add an object with gradient shades it is leaving out a sharp edge. Not giving out the smooth fade out endings.

Comment: @Hani92 mesh tool is way cool but it takes practice to master anyway you can try out that method too :D after all if you learn mesh tool you'll enjoy illustrator even more :D

Comment: @DesignPhoenix Okay, I will check that out! Thanks :D

Comment: Can't you merely set the left side mesh point(s) to be white? There's no need for masking anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use Opacity Mask**

*It's lifesaver when you need to make something complex comps :D I personally use it a lot in both Illustrator and Photoshop!*

I'll try to explain the steps which I personally Follows!

> 1. Make sure you have opened Transparency window by <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F10</kbd> or window->transparency.
> 2. Create a rectangle or any shape and fill a gradient color in it but make sure the both color should be pure black and pure white ( basically the white colored part will be shown and the black colored part will be hidden after mask )
> 3. Select rectangle and your path and click on Make mask :D and voila you're done.

I shared little video to help out more! Cheers!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat guesswork since I can't see the mesh points in your screenshots.

However, I don't see why you need to mask anything.

Merely select the mesh point(s) on the left and set their color to **white**. They will fade the mesh to white on that side.

[image]

---

Sometimes with meshes it's easier to start with *rudimentary shapes* and adjust. This is what I would do here -- start with a simple rectangular mesh and then move and adjust the mesh points to match the desired shape.

[Here is a large (1MB) gif animation showing this procedure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiSjP.gif)

Comment: <I can only do this much using gradient tool in illustrator.> He said that he used gradient tool instead of mesh pr gradient mesh though i reproduced same situation by making stroke gradient :D since at first sight even i thought it's mesh tool!

Comment: *"How can I fade an object which uses the gradient **or mesh tool**?"* `:)`

Comment: OMG! that's it lol sometimes i should read title x10 times too instead of only post :D +1 already for your answer  :)

Comment: I didn't know how I can do it masking or mesh since I am new using illustrator. I made that using a normal gradient option in stroke. Someone edited the title here. But thank you. I didn't know I can use mesh tool like that.